# Can't choose a repository for git installation

Tags: windows, git

I am installing git on Windows Server 2008 virtual machine from this [link](https://git-scm.com/download/win) , however nowhere in the installation process I see an option for selecting a directory where to install. It just installs itself in \AppData\Local\Programs however I need it to be in C:\Program Files (x86). Is there any way to change this? Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

When you download the 64-bit Git for Windows Setup, the executable installs in your Downloads directory. From there, if you run it, in the second step of the installation process called **Select Destination Location,** it asks you to specify the directory to which you want Git installed - there you can choose the destination path. Why don't you try again?

Comment: I tried it on my laptop and it shows the option to select a directory, you are right. I discovered this problem on Windows Server 2008 virtual machine, when I try to install it, the selection doesnt show up, it jumps to Select Components view.

Comment: @gfels oh that's weird - do not know why the executable omits the selection on Win Server 2008 :/